# Why does msbuild appear to ignore which projects are in a solution?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

We have a solution that contains some projects. The projects have references to other projects outside the solution. In Visual Studio, the build fails as the dependent projects are missing from the solution while using msbuild, the build succeeds.

It appears that msbuild is using the path to the projects' dependants to recursively build the dependencies. This seems to be the difference between the msbuild behaviour and the Visual Studio behaviour.

If I am right in this assumption, is there a way of turning off this recursive build behaviour? We want consistent behaviour between build server and Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Remove the references.

Comment: The Visual Studio behaviour is the behaviour we are after. The solution defines what a product consists of. The failure indicates there is a project that should be managed as part of our product that is missing.